# Mutate tuple of lists getting "'tuple' object does not support item assignment“

Tags: python, list, tuples, immutability

I'm trying to modify a list in a tuple, the `append` method works, while `+=` operator works yet with an exception raised saying tuple could not be modified. I know a tuple is immutable, but I'm not trying to mutate it. Why this happen?

```
In [36]: t=([1,2],)

In [37]: t[0].append(123)

In [38]: t
Out[38]: ([1, 2, 123],)

In [39]: t[0]+=[4,5,]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-b5b3001fbe03> in <module>()
----> 1 t[0]+=[4,5,]

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

In [40]: t
Out[40]: ([1, 2, 123, 4, 5],)
```

Comment: Also see the [official explanation in the Python FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-does-a-tuple-i-item-raise-an-exception-when-the-addition-works).

Comment: @user2357112, thank you~ and thank all the answers below! I was thinking there must be an answer for this, just didn't know how to describe and Google this ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`+=` is the in-place addition operator. It does *two* things:

- it calls `obj.__iadd__(rhs)` to give the object the *opportunity* to mutate the object in-place.
- it rebinds the reference to whatever the `obj.__iadd__(rhs)` call returns.

By using `+=` on a list stored in a tuple, the first step succeeds; the `t[0]` list is altered in-place, but the second step, rebinding `t[0]` to the return value of `t[0].__iadd__` fails because a tuple is immutable.

The latter step is needed to support the same operator on both mutable and immutable objects:

```
>>> reference = somestr = 'Hello'
>>> somestr += ' world!'
>>> somestr
'Hello world!'
>>> reference
'Hello'
>>> reference is somestr
False
```

Here a immutable string was added to, and `somestr` was rebound to a *new* object, because strings are immutable.

```
>>> reference = somelst = ['foo']
>>> somelst += ['bar']
>>> somelst
['foo', 'bar']
>>> reference
['foo', 'bar']
>>> reference is somestr
True
```

Here the list was altered in-place and `somestr` was rebound to the *same object*, because `list.__iadd__()` can alter the list object in-place.

From the [augmented arithmetic special method hooks documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__):

> These methods are called to implement the augmented arithmetic assignments (`+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `//=`, `%=`, `**=`, `<<=`, `>>=`, `&=`, `^=`, `|=`). These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying `self`) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, `self`).

The work-around here is to call `t[0].extend()` instead:

```
>>> t = ([1,2],)
>>> t[0].extend([3, 4, 5])
>>> t[0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning "opportunity"

Answer (score 4):

Because `t[0] += [4,5,]` is interpreted as:

```
t[0] = t[0].__iadd__([4,5,])
```

`t[0]__iadd__([4,5])` succeed, while `t[0] = ..` fail.

---

`list.__iadd__` extend the list, and return itself.

```
>>> lst = [0]
>>> lst2 = lst.__iadd__([1])
>>> lst
[0, 1]
>>> lst2
[0, 1]
>>> lst is lst2
True
```

Comment: +1 for 'and return itself' , thx

Answer (score 1):

In fact you **do** change the tuple:

The `+` operator for lists creates a new list and you try to mutate your tuple by replacing the old list by the new one. `append`modifies the list in the tuple, therefore it works.

Comment: I don't think I'm **replacing** the old list with a new one, since `l=[1,]; print id(l); l+=[3]; print id(l)` prints the same id.

Comment: @zhangxaochen: In-place addition on a mutable object does two things:  Mutate the object, and return `self`, so that the reference can be re-bound.

Answer (score 1):

When we say tuple is immutable, it means that the elements of a tuple (which are references to other objects), cannot be changed (read as, cannot be made to refer other objects).

So, when you say,

```
t[0].append(123)
```

You are not changing the element at index 0, to refer some other object. Instead, you are making changes to the same object, which is perfectly okay as per the tuple.

When you say,

```
t[0] += [4,5,]
```

Python internally calls `__iadd__` (stands for inplace add) method, which can be understood like this

```
t[0] = t[0] + [4,5,]
```

which means that, we take the object `t[0]`, adding it with `[4,5,]` to get a new object and that new object is being **assigned** back to `t[0]`. Now we are trying to mutate the tuple (making an element of a tuple refer to some other object).

That is why you see

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

in the later case.